# Dog peeing inside

Tags: dogs, urination

We have a 12 year old chihuahua that keeps peeing in the house. It's mostly on the linoleum, but sometimes on the carpet. I have no idea why he keeps doing this. There is a doggy door, which he used to use, but not anymore.

A few things have changed since he used to use the doggy door. We had a second child (now 4 years old). We took in a stray dog, lab mix. The new dog definitely holds it to do her business outside. The new dog has her own bed inside, but spends most of the day outside. The chihuahua pretty much has his own couch to lay on. If we mop the whole floor, he will pee several times, in different places. I woke up to 4 pee spots this AM, after mopping yesterday. It's like he's trying to mark territory.

When the chihuahua pees inside, sometimes we put down paper towels to soak it up before cleaning, and sometimes he will pee again on the paper towels. If we can't get him to use the doggy door, what can we do to get him to at least pee in the same place? Possibly on the "go here" pads?

This is really pissing me off (pun intended), how can I mitigate this?

Please suggest appropriate tags.

Comment: Any new changes in behavior like urinating or defecating in the house should be addressed by a veterinarian, it very well could be a medical concern.